# cakephp email html symbol in subject

Tags: email, cakephp, htmlspecialchars

I am using cakephp 2.3. For sending email I am using CakeEmail now the subject have some html symbol like É which are not viewing well in delivered email.

Please help how can fix this problem, 
I have try with

> $email->headerCharset = "utf-8";

but it did not worked.
I try enough to google but failed.

```
$email = new CakeEmail();
$email->from(array('test@testing.com' => 'My Email Test')); 
$email->to(array('test1@testing.com'));

$email->subject('New Form É Request From User'); 
$email->headerCharset = "utf-8"; 
$email->emailFormat('html');
$body="Requested new form is attached";
$body= "New requested from URL is here ";   
if ($email->send()) {
    echo "email sent";  
} else {    
    echo "email not sent";  
}
```

Comment: The email class will work with utf8 out of the box if you whole application is utf8 and properly configured. No need to modify any headerCharset attributes. How do you add those? From po files? Or hardcoded in the class file? The latter requires your class file to be saves as utf-8 as well in order for this char to be used/delivered correctly.

Comment: I have add the code in question which I am using, could you please help in detail how to resolve the problem

Comment: You did not. As the char you mentioned is nowhere to be seen :) Rule number one is: Never make stuff up.

Comment: actually I have to E with small slash (&#201;) and TM as sub script (&#8482;).

Comment: Is the file saves as utf8 without BOM?

Comment: File is saved in ANSI format

Comment: That is your problem when using "É" etc in your code. Its fine to do so - as long you save it properly. Did you try my suggestion? Does it then work?

Comment: I try with save the file as utf8 without BOM and give the subject "New Form É Request From User" but in gmail I can just see "New Form Request From User" in subject.  "É" is not shown in email subject

Comment: Will you please give any other hint?